# jQuery.html() method is not working appropriately on IE7 and IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I been working with jQuery for a while, but recently I've encountered a problem with IE7 and IE8 while using jQuery's **.html()** method. Id I receive an XML response from an AJAX call and try to get the innerHTML of a particular segment of that response I get an undefined.

Now this works prefectly on Firefox, Chrome and IE 9.

Please see the snippet below:

```
 var data = 
     "<reponse_data>" + 
     "  <chart_data>" + 
     "      <chart caption='' yAxisName='Unidades' alternateVGridColor='AFD8F8' toolTipBorderColor='114B78' toolTipBgColor='E7EFF6' plotBorderDashed='0' plotBorderDashLen='2' plotBorderDashGap='2'  useRoundEdges='1' showBorder='1' bgColor='FFFFFF,FFFFFF' formatNumberScale='0' paletteColors='B9E1FF,FEC618,94C20A,CD7239,0A9797'>" + 
     "          <set label='Inventario' value='1203' />" + 
     "          <set label='Recibidas' value='3423' />" + 
     "          <set label='Subastadas' value='3661' />" + 
     "          <set label='Entregadas' value='3648'  />" + 
     "          <set label='Balance' value='978'  />" + 
     "      </chart>" + 
     "  </chart_data>" + 
     "  <misc>" + 
     "      <initialInvCell>1,203</initialInvCell>" + 
     "      <receivedUnitsCell>3,423</receivedUnitsCell>" + 
     "      <auctionedUnitsCell>3,661</auctionedUnitsCell>" + 
     "      <deliveredUnitsCell>3,648</deliveredUnitsCell>" + 
     "      <finalInventoryCell>978</finalInventoryCell>" + 
     "  </misc>" + 
     "</reponse_data>";

 console.log('ChartData: ' + $(data).find('chart_data').html());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @teewuane and @joshua,

Thank you for all your help. I was able to succeed in achieving my goal by doing the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/CcWfj/3/

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function ieParse () {
            //var xmlText = "<root><fruit color='red'></fruit></root>";
            var xmlText = "<reponse_data>" + 
                          "   <chart_data>" + 
                          "       <chart caption='' yAxisName='Unidades' alternateVGridColor='AFD8F8' toolTipBorderColor='114B78'     toolTipBgColor='E7EFF6' plotBorderDashed='0' plotBorderDashLen='2' plotBorderDashGap='2'  useRoundEdges='1' showBorder='1'     bgColor='FFFFFF,FFFFFF' formatNumberScale='0' paletteColors='B9E1FF,FEC618,94C20A,CD7239,0A9797'>" + 
                          "           <set label='Inventario' value='1203' />" + 
                          "           <set label='Recibidas' value='3423' />" + 
                          "           <set label='Subastadas' value='3661' />" + 
                          "           <set label='Entregadas' value='3648'  />" + 
                          "           <set label='Balance' value='978'  />" + 
                          "       </chart>" + 
                          "   </chart_data>" + 
                          "   <misc>" + 
                          "       <initialInvCell>1,203</initialInvCell>" + 
                          "       <receivedUnitsCell>3,423</receivedUnitsCell>" + 
                          "       <auctionedUnitsCell>3,661</auctionedUnitsCell>" + 
                          "       <deliveredUnitsCell>3,648</deliveredUnitsCell>" + 
                          "       <finalInventoryCell>978</finalInventoryCell>" + 
                          "   </misc>" + 
                          "</reponse_data>";

            var xmlDocument = XMLFromString(xmlText);
            var chartData = XMLToString(xmlDocument.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0]);
            var elementsData = XMLToString(xmlDocument.childNodes[0].childNodes[1]);

            alert(chartData);
            alert(elementsData);

        }

        function XMLToString(oXML) {
          if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            return oXML.xml;
          } else {
            return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(oXML);
          }
        }

        function XMLFromString(sXML) {
          if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var oXML = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            oXML.loadXML(sXML);
            return oXML;
          } else {
            return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(sXML, "text/xml");
          }
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="ieParse ()">IE Parse</button>
</body>
```

So I basically had to scrap the use of jQuery's .find() and .html() function all together for IE7 and IE8.

And Joshua I'll take your comments into advicement.

I used the following reference:
http://joncom.be/code/javascript-xml-conversion/

Thanks again,

Answer (score 3):

`$(data)` is not HTML yet. It's a string, and as such it doesn't have any of the DOM associated with it that jQuery uses. You need to dump it into the DOM somewhere before trying to use it with jQuery.

Since you're getting this as a string from somewhere, maybe the best thing to do (performance and memory-wise) is parse the string and get the values you want. You can use either RegEx, or find the indexes of the opening and closing brackets and get whatever's in between.

Comment: OK, what I placed above is an over simplified version of the code. The XML above is just a response that I get as a result of an .ajax() call. So you're basically saying that if I dump this response into an invisible div and fetch it from there it should work? Could it work if I do somethig like: $('<div>').append(data).html()

Comment: Hi @cem I did try it I was just trying to make sure that we were on the same page. If your not going to provide useful input stop flaming on the thread. If you read on you'll see both my tests. I have tried everything that he has proposed, and then some.

Comment: I'm sorry if you thought that was meant rude. I just read 'does it work, when …', which, in my humble opinion, states that you did not tried it on your own. Just wan't to keep the quality up here :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I've updated my answer. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrqS7/1/) to see it working...

Note this is using jquery 1.8.2

html:

```
<div id="maincontent">
    hello world
</div>​
```

js:

```
var data = 
 "<reponse_data>" + 
 "  <chart_data>" + 
 "      <chart caption='' yAxisName='Unidades' alternateVGridColor='AFD8F8' toolTipBorderColor='114B78' toolTipBgColor='E7EFF6' plotBorderDashed='0' plotBorderDashLen='2' plotBorderDashGap='2'  useRoundEdges='1' showBorder='1' bgColor='FFFFFF,FFFFFF' formatNumberScale='0' paletteColors='B9E1FF,FEC618,94C20A,CD7239,0A9797'>" + 
 "          <set label='Inventario' value='1203' />" + 
 "          <set label='Recibidas' value='3423' />" + 
 "          <set label='Subastadas' value='3661' />" + 
 "          <set label='Entregadas' value='3648'  />" + 
 "          <set label='Balance' value='978'  />" + 
 "      </chart>" + 
 "  </chart_data>" + 
 "  <misc>" + 
 "      <initialInvCell>1,203</initialInvCell>" + 
 "      <receivedUnitsCell>3,423</receivedUnitsCell>" + 
 "      <auctionedUnitsCell>3,661</auctionedUnitsCell>" + 
 "      <deliveredUnitsCell>3,648</deliveredUnitsCell>" + 
 "      <finalInventoryCell>978</finalInventoryCell>" + 
 "  </misc>" + 
"</reponse_data>";

var a = $("<div/>",{
    html: data,
    id: "darth",
    style: "display:none;"
}).appendTo($("#maincontent"));

var b = a.find("chart_data").html();

alert(b);
```

Old answer:

I wouldn't think that would work since it's not really html at that point. It's a string of text until it's injected into the dom...

I would suggest dumping that into the dom first if you want to use methods like .html().

something like...

```
var data = "data" + "more data..." + "more data"...


var a = $("<div/>",{html: data, display: "none"}).appendTo($("body"));
```

then...

```
var b = a.find("chart_data").html();
```

It's not very pretty but it should work...

Comment: I just tried both: 

    var data = "...";//Same as above
    
    $('#placeholder').html(data);
    
    console.log($('#placeholder').find('chart_data').html());
    
As well as 
    var data = "...";//Same as above
 
    var a = $("<div/>",{html: data, display: "none"}).appendTo($("body"));
    var b = a.find("chart_data").html();

    console.log(b);
 
Perfect in Firefox, but no luck in IE7-8.

Comment: @sonar What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: ... i updated my answer. then i tried it in ie8. dang. it didn't work. still working on it.

Comment: It looks great @teewuane, but were you able to try this on IE7 or IE8? Because I tried it by running my IE9 *Browser mode: IE8* and *Document mode: IE8*, and the result was an alert box displaying undefined. In firefox and IE9 it works perfect. I'm testing my code under http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js (1.8.3).

Comment: Oh I hadn't seen you second comment. Thank you for your effort I'm also trying a few thinks here.